Is there a way to remove a linebreak from the textToBePresentInElement waiter?
When using the innerText JS method Chrome and Safari return the text in different formats if there are multiple child elements with text.
We've been using Safari for our tests and when calling getText() or textToBePresentInElement(String) it will return a normal linebreak which is then ignored when using the waiter. But in Chrome, the linebreak is a \n which is not part of the original string, failing the check.
Chrome:
'Beginning\n - Ending'

Safari:
"Beginning
 - Ending
"

I could add the \n to the expected String but it wouldn't represent what we are actually waiting for to be in the element, and it would also break the Safari runs. Is there any other method that would get around this issue?

I think Windows and Mac have slightly different hard line breaks. (windows will use cr + \n for hard line breaks)   You might instead use textContent or innerHTML as those will be the raw DOM, while innerText and Selenium's getText method will attempt to get rendered text.

Probably in the case of javascript, you can go ahead with 'textContent' instead of 'innerText'. textContent would return the entire text including the spaces and line breaks and also the text of child elements
